# React.render() is giving error when we create component in one js file and render it in another js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, rendering

I am new to Reactjs. I have downloaded the latest bundle of JS files from: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html

I set path for the JavaScript files in my HTML file and started working on it.

When I create a component in the same file and render the component in same JavaScript file it works fine. But when I create a component in one JavaScript file and render it in another JavaScript file by importing, it is giving me error.

Below is the sample code, which is working:

```
var FindEmp= React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return(
                <p>EMPID <input type='text'/></p>
                );
    }
});

React.render(<FindEmp/> , document.getElementById('content'))
```

and if write this in 2 files like below its not working

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var React = require('react/addons');
var FindEmp= require('./components/FindEmp.react');


React.render(<FindEmp/> , document.getElementById('content'));  //This Line is                    giving me error saying
```

**FindEmp.react.js**

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactPropTypes = React.PropTypes;

var FindEmp = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return(
                <p>EMP ID <input type='text'/></p>
                );
    }
});
module.exports = FindEmp;
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
    <script src="lib/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/react.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/react-with-addons.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/marked.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/jsx" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx">

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: I am using browser.js

Comment: Even I tried babel in command line using npm. when I execute webpack -w . it says webpack is not an internal or external command.. I tried the note taker tutorial video  for this in the site https://egghead.io/series/build-your-first-react-js-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this sample I was using react.js file . Removed the js file and started using npm react tools and web pack. This solved my problem.
 I have gone through the following site for a sample..
http://jmfurlott.com/tutorial-setting-up-a-single-page-react-web-app-with-react-router-and-webpack/

Answer (score 0):

You did missed

```
 <div id="content"></div>
```

so

```
 document.getElementById('content')
```

cant find anything.
And its important to put it **above** reference to your app.js.

Comment: Oh Thanks for the correction. Now I am getting the error : Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: In first of all I must admit that I'm also new with React and just trying to learn by doing, so pls forgive me my mistakes.
Anyway, it looks strange for me to use require at client side.

Your program starts from index.html and everything runs in browser on client side, so there are no _require_ or such nodeJS things.

You can simply split your code into 2 separate files then include both of them with <script type="text/jsx" src="name.here"></script>